# I am getting a "reading init" error from the package "aad_auth" in flutter

Tags: flutter, authentication, azure-active-directory

The [example code](https://pub.dev/packages/aad_oauth) is working fine for android, but giving

> Type error (for web) : Cannot read properties of undefined(reading init)

Please suggest a solution or a different package for web.

Comment: Have you found this solution @17-477 Pavan

Comment: yes, had to add some lines to html file.